# ConEmu (CMD) not indentifying these unicode characters?

Tags: java, conemu

```
public void print(boolean nextLine, int delayInt, String load) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(System.out, true,"UTF-8");
    for(int x = 0; x < load.length(); x++ ){
        p.print(load.charAt(x));
        try{
            Thread.sleep(delayInt);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(nextLine)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Alright the above is a method to print every character in the String, I am using PrintStream because I felt it will allow me to use all Unicode characters when I compile and execute the Java program in ConEmu (which I am using instead of CMD @ Windows)

```
i.print(true, 50,"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "▓█████▄         ██▓         ██████         ▄████▄          ▒█████          ██▒   █▓       ▓█████         ██▀███         \n" +
            "▒██▀ ██▌       ▓██▒       ▒██    ▒        ▒██▀ ▀█         ▒██▒  ██▒       ▓██░   █▒       ▓█   ▀        ▓██ ▒ ██▒       \n" +
            "░██   █▌       ▒██▒       ░ ▓██▄          ▒▓█    ▄        ▒██░  ██▒        ▓██  █▒░       ▒███          ▓██ ░▄█ ▒       \n" +
            "░▓█▄   ▌       ░██░         ▒   ██▒       ▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒       ▒██   ██░         ▒██ █░░       ▒▓█  ▄        ▒██▀▀█▄         \n" +
            "░▒████▓        ░██░       ▒██████▒▒       ▒ ▓███▀ ░       ░ ████▓▒░          ▒▀█░         ░▒████▒       ░██▓ ▒██▒       \n" +
            " ▒▒▓  ▒        ░▓         ▒ ▒▓▒ ▒ ░       ░ ░▒ ▒  ░       ░ ▒░▒░▒░           ░ ▐░         ░░ ▒░ ░       ░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░       \n" +
            " ░ ▒  ▒         ▒ ░       ░ ░▒  ░ ░         ░  ▒            ░ ▒ ▒░           ░ ░░          ░ ░  ░         ░▒ ░ ▒░       \n" +
            " ░ ░  ░         ▒ ░       ░  ░  ░         ░               ░ ░ ░ ▒              ░░            ░            ░░   ░        \n" +
            "   ░            ░               ░         ░ ░                 ░ ░               ░            ░  ░          ░            \n" +
            " ░                                        ░                                    ░                                        \n" +
            "\n"
    );
    i.print(true, 2, "\n" +
            "\n" +
            " ▄█         ▄████████                                                                                                                                       \n" +
            "███        ███    ███                                                                                                                                       \n" +
            "███▌       ███    ███                                                                                                                                       \n" +
            "███▌       ███    ███                                                                                                                                       \n" +
            "███▌     ▀███████████                                                                                                                                       \n" +
            "███        ███    ███                                                                                                                                       \n" +
            "███        ███    ███                                                                                                                                       \n" +
            "█▀         ███    █▀                                                                                                                                        \n" +
            "                                                                                                                                                            \n" +
            " ▄█   ▄█   ▄█      ▀█████████▄         ▄████████      ▄█       ▄████████        ▄█   ▄█▄      ▄█   ▄█   ▄█                                                  \n" +
            "███  ███  ███        ███    ███       ███    ███     ███      ███    ███       ███ ▄███▀     ███  ███  ███                                                  \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌       ███    ███       ███    ███     ███▌     ███    █▀        ███▐██▀       ███▌ ███▌ ███▌                                                 \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌      ▄███▄▄▄██▀       ▄███▄▄▄▄██▀     ███▌     ███             ▄█████▀        ███▌ ███▌ ███▌                                                 \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌     ▀▀███▀▀▀██▄      ▀▀███▀▀▀▀▀       ███▌     ███            ▀▀█████▄        ███▌ ███▌ ███▌                                                 \n" +
            "███  ███  ███        ███    ██▄     ▀███████████     ███      ███    █▄        ███▐██▄       ███  ███  ███                                                  \n" +
            "███  ███  ███        ███    ███       ███    ███     ███      ███    ███       ███ ▀███▄     ███  ███  ███                                                  \n" +
            "█▀   █▀   █▀       ▄█████████▀        ███    ███     █▀       ████████▀        ███   ▀█▀     █▀   █▀   █▀                                                   \n" +
            "                                      ███    ███                               ▀                                                                            \n" +
            " ▄█   ▄█   ▄█      ▀█████████▄         ▄████████        ▄████████        ▄████████        ▄█   ▄█▄        ▄████████        ▄████████      ▄█   ▄█   ▄█      \n" +
            "███  ███  ███        ███    ███       ███    ███       ███    ███       ███    ███       ███ ▄███▀       ███    ███       ███    ███     ███  ███  ███      \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌       ███    ███       ███    ███       ███    █▀        ███    ███       ███▐██▀         ███    █▀        ███    ███     ███▌ ███▌ ███▌     \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌      ▄███▄▄▄██▀       ▄███▄▄▄▄██▀      ▄███▄▄▄           ███    ███      ▄█████▀         ▄███▄▄▄          ▄███▄▄▄▄██▀     ███▌ ███▌ ███▌     \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌     ▀▀███▀▀▀██▄      ▀▀███▀▀▀▀▀       ▀▀███▀▀▀         ▀███████████     ▀▀█████▄        ▀▀███▀▀▀         ▀▀███▀▀▀▀▀       ███▌ ███▌ ███▌     \n" +
            "███  ███  ███        ███    ██▄     ▀███████████       ███    █▄        ███    ███       ███▐██▄         ███    █▄      ▀███████████     ███  ███  ███      \n" +
            "███  ███  ███        ███    ███       ███    ███       ███    ███       ███    ███       ███ ▀███▄       ███    ███       ███    ███     ███  ███  ███      \n" +
            "█▀   █▀   █▀       ▄█████████▀        ███    ███       ██████████       ███    █▀        ███   ▀█▀       ██████████       ███    ███     █▀   █▀   █▀       \n" +
            "                                      ███    ███                                         ▀                                ███    ███                        \n" +
            " ▄█   ▄█   ▄█         ▄████████        ▄████████     ████████▄       ███    █▄         ▄████████      ▄█            ▄█   ▄█   ▄█                            \n" +
            "███  ███  ███        ███    ███       ███    ███     ███    ███      ███    ███       ███    ███     ███           ███  ███  ███                            \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌       ███    █▀        ███    █▀      ███    ███      ███    ███       ███    █▀      ███           ███▌ ███▌ ███▌                           \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌       ███             ▄███▄▄▄         ███    ███      ███    ███      ▄███▄▄▄         ███           ███▌ ███▌ ███▌                           \n" +
            "███▌ ███▌ ███▌     ▀███████████     ▀▀███▀▀▀         ███    ███      ███    ███     ▀▀███▀▀▀         ███           ███▌ ███▌ ███▌                           \n" +
            "███  ███  ███               ███       ███    █▄      ███    ███      ███    ███       ███    █▄      ███           ███  ███  ███                            \n" +
            "███  ███  ███         ▄█    ███       ███    ███     ███  ▀ ███      ███    ███       ███    ███     ███▌    ▄     ███  ███  ███                            \n" +
            "█▀   █▀   █▀        ▄████████▀        ██████████      ▀██████▀▄█     ████████▀        ██████████     █████▄▄██     █▀   █▀   █▀                             \n" +
            "                                                                                                     ▀                                                      \n" +
            " ▄█                                                                                                                                                         \n" +
            "███                                                                                                                                                         \n" +
            "███▌                                                                                                                                                        \n" +
            "███▌                                                                                                                                                        \n" +
            "███▌                                                                                                                                                        \n" +
            "███                                                                                                                                                         \n" +
            "███                                                                                                                                                         \n" +
            "█▀                                                                                                                                                          \n" +
            "                                                                                                                                                            \n" +
            "\n" +
            " \n");
```

However on an IDE as expected it does run, but on ConEmu it shows, 
"testing.java:50: error: unmappable character (0x90) for encoding windows-1252" error I have checked for solutions but they are only for when I have the '\uXXXX' character code which in this case I don't since I have used an online ASCII Art Generator.
[ASCII ART Generator which I have used](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20)

Answer (score 1):

According to [ConEmu documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/UnicodeSupport.html):

> **UTF-8 (UTF8)**
>
> On Windows, unlike Unix, the console itself is not a stream of ‘bytes’ but a spreadsheet of cells, each of which contains an UTF-16 character and a color attribute.
>
> That means if your application produces output using single-byte or multi-byte character sets (which are ANSI, OEM, UTF-8 and many others) the Windows converts that output to UTF-16 automatically regarding active codepage selected in your console (run chcp from console command prompt to check your active codepage).
>
> If you want to work with UTF-8 encoding you have to select UTF-8 as active console codepage. Just run  chcp 65001 command to do that. You may call this command from your shell prompt or run it before shell in a ConEmu task content. Of course your application must be able to output data using UTF-8. Refer to your application manual.

Just enter in your ConEmu terminal and you'll able to see UTF-8 content:

```
chcp 65001
```

Also you have to modify your source code a little and save it as UTF-8 file:

```
public void print(boolean nextLine, int delayInt, String load) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    for(int x = 0; x < load.length(); x++ ){

        // Use the regular System.out.print here to output chars!
        System.out.print(load.charAt(x));

        try{
            Thread.sleep(delayInt);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(nextLine)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Compile run script:

```
chcp 65001
java test
```

The result I get in my ConEmu console:
[image]

Comment: .\Introduction.java:84: error: unmappable character (0x90) for encoding windows-1252 this is the error I am getting again and again, I have made all the possible amendments. I have checked that the CHCP is active @ 65001, yet this error is prompted.

Comment: @lafeo_007, I use Far Manager to edit and save .java file in UTF-8 encoding (65001) using F4, Shift-F8, F2 hotkeys.